# Calling a Powershell script from another software

Tags: powershell, shellexecute

I try to run a Powershell script from TeXworks, a LaTeX editor. The call itself works but I get an error message stating that the execution of scripts is deactivated on this system. I already tried setting the execution-policy to `unrestricted` or `bypass`, same result. Same result also when TeXworks was run as admin. I can execute the script manually without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be setting the unrestricted in 32bit / 64 bit console and trying it out in 64 bit / 32 bit app. Set it in the right console, or in both.

```
32-bit
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

64-bit
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Comment: This means, that the execution policy can be different for 32 and 64 bit, or? For the 32-bit version I set unrestricted, for the 64-bit version I have bypass now. I thought, both versions would use the same regkeys.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen - It's different for the two.

Answer (score 0):

What scope did you set?
Try starting PowerShell with administrator privileges and enter this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Scope LocalMachine
```